# Disabled Pinch Zoom on Mac Touchpad with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, zooming, gestures

Is there anyway to disable the pinch zooming available on mac's touchpad on the desktop?

I tried adding:

```
<meta content='True' name='HandheldFriendly' />
<meta content='width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;' name='viewport' />
```

but this did nothing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar problem where I wanted to disable pinch-zoom gesture on windows machine, here's javascript code snippet that worked for me

```js
window.addEventListener('wheel', (e) => {
    if (e.ctrlKey) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}, {
    "passive": false
});
```

FYI - Along with disabling the pinch-zoom functionality it also disables ctrl+mouse wheel up/down event functionality.

[jsbin POC](https://jsbin.com/nimogetexe/edit?html,console,output)